# CKEditor Native Spell Checker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ckeditor, spell-checking

I'm using the CKEditor and enabled the native spell checker but I have I problem.

I'm setting some default content to the editor using the setData() method, since it's some "Lorem ipsum" text I'm expecting to see almost every word highlighted by the spell checker.

It works that way in Firefox but not in Chrome, for Chrome I have to move the cursor or click somewhere to get the words highlighted by the spell checker.

Does anyone know if the words can be highlighted in Chrome just like in Firefox? Without having to move the cursor or click on the text.

Thanks

Comment: There may be an answer for this particular problem. However, do be aware that we've found many issues with spellcheck in different browsers. (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari all experiencing different issues) when using a contenteditable div. You will likely run into issues down the road too.